# Is there a numpy function to randomly sample multiple probabilities

Tags: python, numpy, statistics, probability, sampling

I have an array of probabilities that I'd like to sample.

Say `p=[0.5,0.9,0.1,0.4]`. I'd like to sample an array of 0,1 and length 4 that uses the probability provided.

Essentially using a vectorized version of `np.random.choice(2,len(p),p=[1-p,p])`

Comment: So 0.9 is the probably of drawing 1 the second time

Comment: @DaniMesejo can think of each probability as independent weighted coin flips

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One approach is to generate an array from a uniform distribution and compare it against the values in `p`:

```
import numpy as np

p = [0.5, 0.9, 0.1, 0.4]

res = (np.random.random(len(p)) < p).astype(np.uint32)
print(res)
```

**Output** *(of a single run)*

```
[0 1 0 0]
```

As an alternative you can consider each value to be draw from a [Bernoulli distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli_distribution), and given that (quote):

> The Bernoulli distribution is a special case of the binomial
> distribution where a single trial is conducted (so n would be 1 for
> such a binomial distribution)

you could do:

```
p = [0.5, 0.9, 0.1, 0.4]
res = np.random.binomial(1, p, size=len(p))
print(res)
```

**Output** *(of a single run)*

```
[0 1 0 1]
```

Note that [`np.random.binomial`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/random/generated/numpy.random.binomial.html) accepts as argument `p` an array. From the documentation (emphasis mine):

> **p float or array_like of floats**
> Parameter of the distribution, >= 0 and <=1.